# Calling a python method

Tags: python

I have a file `notifications.py` and `comments.py`. notifications has a class `GetNotifications` with a function `getNotifs(arg1, arg2)`. I'd like to call this method in my comments.py, so I do:

`from notifications import GetNotifications`

Then I create an instance of the class:

```
getNotifsInstance = GetNotifications()
```

Then I try to call getNotifs:

```
notifsDictionary = getNotifsInstance.getNotifs(arg1, arg2)
```

However, I'm getting the error:
`TypeError: getNotifs() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Why is it saying I'm giving it 3 arguments when I'm only giving it 2?

Comment: When you call a method of an instance it always passes itself as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're giving it three arguments: when you call an instance method, the instance is passed as the first parameter. You should add an argument `self` as the first parameter of the method.

Answer (score 3):

You've most probably forgotten about the `self` argument when declaring `getNotifs()`:

```
def getNotifs(self, arg1, arg2):
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it saying I'm giving it 3 arguments when I'm only giving it 2?

Simply because you are accessing the function `getNotifys` as a member function of object `getNotifsInstance`. The first argument to any member function is (`self`) the object reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the class you can define **three kinds of methods**:

```
class A(object):
    def instance_method(*args):
        print '%d arguments given' % len(args)
    @classmethod
    def class_method(*args):
        print '%d arguments given' % len(args)
    @staticmethod
    def static_method(*args):
        print '%d arguments given' % len(args)
```

And when you invoke them on the instance, **you will get additional argument passed to instance method** (which will be instance itself) **and class method** (which will be a class of the instance):

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.instance_method('a', 'b')
3 arguments given
>>> a.class_method('a', 'b')
3 arguments given
>>> a.static_method('a', 'b')
2 arguments given
```

In your case it is probably `self` (the instance itself), although results would be similar if you would decorate your method with `classmethod` decorator (in that case you would get a class passed as the first argument).